# Navbar not sitting correctly within wrap,

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am learning to create my first website and I've ran into the first problem that I can't solve. I have a navigation bar in which I want to sit nicely within a wrap but the navigation bar sits beneath it and I can't seem to get it right.

Advice would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4pHZ/2/

HTML

```
<div class="links_container">
    <div class="nav1">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="noBorder leftedge">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Challenges</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="rightedge">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.links_container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #33C4AB;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
    /* [disabled]-webkit-box-sizing: inherit; */
    /* [disabled]-moz-box-sizing: inherit; */
    /* [disabled]box-sizing: inherit; */
    position: absolute;
}

.nav1 {
    float: left;
}
.nav1 ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.nav1 ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333333;
    display: inherit;
    height: 35px;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-left: thin solid #CCCCCC;
}
.noBorder {
    border-left-style: none !important;
}
.nav1 ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    height: 35px;
}
.leftedge {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.rightedge {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
*{
margin:0;
}
```

and/or

```
.nav1 ul {
    display: inline;
}
```

The first code will remove the default browser margin from the webpage, and the second code will display `.nav1 ul` as an inline element

Also, it's a good idea to think about removing `.nav1{float:left;}` since it doesn't affect anything, and change the `.links_container` width to 100% instead of 1000px.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4pHZ/4/)

Comment: That seems to have worked great! Thanks! Just so I understand, was it the browser default margin that was causing it not to fit in?

Also, for some reason it seems there is an indent at the start of the navigation bar and I cannot seem to get it centered in the wrap. Is there a quick fix for this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that the browser default margin was causing it to go down, but `.nav1 ul{display:inline;}` will solve both fitting and indent problems. If you want to center the navigation bar inside the wrap, try using `.nav1 { position:absolute; right:50%; margin-right:-325px; }`. While `right:0` will put the left side of the nav in the center, `margin-right:-325px;` will put the it 325px (half of nav width) to the left, centering it. [**Here's the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/z4pHZ/5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline` for your `ul`

```
.nav1 ul {
    display: inline;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4pHZ/3/)**